# Dynamically get the list of data constructors of a type

Tags: haskell, reflection, types

I have a data type like this:

`data ABCS = A Int | B Int | ... | Z Int deriving (Data, Typeable)`

In a test, I want to dynamically extract all the constructors, make an instance from each constructor, then run the test.

I have been looking through `Data.Typeable` and `Data.Data`, but I have not yet seen/understood exactly how to do this starting with only the type (ABC).

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does [`Arbitrary`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.9.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Arbitrary.html) already do what you want (without resorting to `Data.Data`)? Otherwise, what are the arguments you would like fed to the constructors?

Comment: Basically I want to join a list of numbers with the list of constructors. But I want to dynamically get the list of constructors.

Comment: `Arbitrary` does not help me in this case. I am not looking to randomly generate data. I want to test a condition for every data instance.

Comment: You might also want to look at whatever `smallcheck` uses to generate test cases. Unlike quickcheck, it's designed for exhaustive testing.

Comment: @dfeuer I think the answer might be to actually use smallcheck! Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're OK with using `Data.Data`, it works for this use case, but is a little clunky because of the `Int` parameters.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.Data
import Data.Typeable

allCtors :: forall a. Data a => [Int -> a]
allCtors = map observeCtor $ dataTypeConstrs $ dataTypeOf (undefined :: a)
  where
    observeCtor :: Constr -> Int -> a
    observeCtor c i = fromJust $ fromConstrM (cast i) c
```

Then we have e.g.

```
λ data ABC = A Int | B Int | C Int deriving (Show, Data, Typeable)
data ABC = A Int | B Int | C Int
λ map ($ 2) allCtors :: [ABC]
[A 2,B 2,C 2]
```

If you don't want to use `Data.Data`, you might to be able to do this with `GHC.Generics` and `-XDefaultSignatures`

---

FWIW, you wouldn't have to deal with any of this if you could refactor ABC so that the A,B,C tags were their own type...

```
data ABCTagged = ABCTagged ABC Int deriving Show

data ABC = A | B | C deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Enum. Bounded)
```

... then just use `enumFrom minBound :: [ABC]` to get the whole list. Easy! Not sure how feasible this is for you though.

Comment: The data type is not my actual data type. It was the simplest example I could make that would express what I am trying to accomplish. So, the tagged example would not work for me. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I am breaking down piece by piece your answer for the sake of my own understanding, and when I execute this `fromConstrM (Just 10 :: Maybe Int) ctor` I get `Couldn't match type ‘d’ with ‘Int’
      ‘d’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a type expected by the context:
          forall d. Data d => Maybe d
        at <interactive>:52:1
      Expected type: Maybe d
        Actual type: Maybe Int` In this case, ctorA does indeed hold a valid `A` constructor `show ctorA` -> "A"

Comment: OK, I have it partially figured out: `let c = cast 10 :: forall d. Data d => Maybe d` then `fromConstrM c ctorA` but I get `Just ()`

Comment: You've got the right idea. `cast 10 :: forall d. Data d => Maybe d` would *almost* work but the type of `10` is going to default to `Integer` so when we try and cast it to `Int` we're going to have a problem.

Issue #2 is that when you call `fromConstrM` you need to be more specific about type since otherwise you'll get a `forall d. Data d => Maybe d` and GHCi is nice enough to default to `d ~ ()` for you.

So the full incantation should be `fromConstrM (cast (10 :: Int)) ctorA :: Maybe ABC`